# last update date of a range stored in the single cell excel

Tags: excel, range

So I have this excel worksheet, where I have a range A2:A3, I would like to know if I can store last time of update of that specific range to a cell lets say in B1?
I am really knew in VBA world.
Will really appreciate any help :)

Comment: should work if any cell of that range changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- right click your sheet tab
- View Code
- copy and paste in the code below
- [alt](/questions/tagged/alt)[f11](/questions/tagged/f11) back to Excel

**`code`**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect([a2:a3], Target)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
[b1] = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But I am just wondering What if I want to do this for two ranges and store them in 2 cells?

Comment: If you look at the link above! .. somehow when I change H35:H52 .. H8 and H9 both get updated. Not Just H9 as I wish to..

Answer (score 0):

'This Macro has been written to update Last modified date/time on each A2:D43415
'Last Modified date applied to column F.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rInt As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Dim tCell As Range
Dim tColInt As Integer

tColInt = 6 'Column Index, Example: A=1, B=2, ...... ,Z=26


Set rInt = Intersect(Target, Range("A2:D43415")) 'Change cell range
 If Not rInt Is Nothing Then
    For Each rCell In rInt
        Set tCell = Cells(rCell.Cells.Row, tColInt)
        If IsEmpty(tCell) Or Not IsEmpty(tCell) Then
            tCell = Now
            tCell.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM" 'Custom Format
        End If
    Next
 End If
End Sub
```

[Click to See Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51vm9.png)